# Doubts about CMS in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

I have been trying to learn a CMS in php. Visited youtube for tutorials. Joomla & Wordpress.
But when they develop a website using a CMS, I didn't see any php code. It's all just working from a dashboard like building a blog.
I am confused about that.

Don't we have to write code in CMS like we do in Core PHP??

Comment: To learn `wordpress`, [http://codex.wordpress.org/](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

Comment: This isn't really the proper format for a question on this site.  But the *dashboard* is run by PHP.  You are best to start learning PHP (web tutorial or book is even better) and then you will understand how it is connected.

Comment: Think of PHP as the engine, and the CMS as the car.  You don't need to know how an engine works to drive a car.  But your car does have a dashboard (same as the CMS) which tells you what is happening to the car.  If you want to make your car do other things (like go faster), you need to know PHP to improve the engine.

Comment: You can be a user of software. You can be a developer of software. You can be both. Using a CMS is different than developing a CMS. As a user, you use its features like posting a blog entry, create static pages, specifying the menus. With developing a CMS you actually program with  different web technologies - PHP, MySql, HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Hi using a CMS you can create a website simply... Wordpress is one of the best content manage system... actually they developed it for easy customization. Only using dashboard you can create pages,blogs etc only... If you want your own **functionality** You have to learn the coding structure and manual **Plugin** creation.
But the fact is You will get so many plugins from **wordpress** depending upon your requirement those it already developed.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner you can use CMS to create a complete site, but to add any real functionality to create specialist sites you will probably have to write you own plugins and/or themes at some point, or edit existing ones.

For this you will need php/jquery/html/whatever.